# How to convert audio file using ffmpeg API?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to convert PCM to flac using only ffmpeg API, but not the ffmpeg binary? I am looking for the full explanation of the process, but not only a solution

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to look at the source of the ffmpeg binary itself, it uses the ffmpeg APIs itself. There are also code samples there. Here's the [ffmpeg source code](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.8.6.tar.bz2).